# How to use Magento2 Module Select2 Ui Component ? How active module in default.xml?

Tags: magento2, module, uicomponent

I succesfull installed Magento2 Module Select2 Ui Component from https://github.com/weprovide/magento2-module-select2-uicomponent

I never had to use UI components. I want to active Select2 on frontend on my category page. Does anyone can help me with that ? Can I just add this Component by refercence to default.xml or default_head_blocks.xml in Magento_Theme/layout ?

```
    <select class="admin__control-select" data-bind="
    attr: {
        name: inputName,
        id: uid,
        disabled: disabled,
        'aria-describedby': noticeId
    },
    hasFocus: focused,
    optgroup: options,
    value: value,
    optionsCaption: caption,
    optionsValue: 'value',
    optionsText: 'label',
    select2: {}
" />
```

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to include select2.js on front-end using **define** or **RequiredJs**
As sample

- JS code

**define**

```
define(['jquery', 'Namespace_ModuleName/js/select2path'], function($){
     $('.control-select2').select2({});
});
```

**requirejs** on phtml file

```
require(['jquery', 'Namespace_ModuleName/js/select2path'],function($){
     $('.control-select2').select2({});
});
```

- HTML code

  ```
   <select class="control-select2">
   <option>option1</option>
   </select>
  ```

let use **WeProvide_Select2UiComponent** module

- HTML Code

  ```
    <select class="control-select2">
        <option>option1</option>
    </select>
  ```
- Javascript Code

  ```
   require(['jquery', 'WeProvide_Select2UiComponent/js/select2','domReady!'],function($){
              $('.control-select2').select2({});
   });
  ```

Comment: I ve used "require(["jquery","jquery/ui","WeProvide_Select2UiComponent/js/select2","domReady!"],function($){
    $('select').select2();
});" but nothing changes to select box.

Comment: Did you check console error log?

Comment: I found something like this      <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Experius_FormSelectChosen/selectChosen</item>
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Experius_FormSelectChosen/js/component/select.chosen</item>     How use this method ?

Comment: It used for backend only, you can't apply this for Frontend.